# Which of these two user interfaces would be more efficient in summarizing a support ticket?

Tags: forms, interface

I'm creating a user interface that will enable a support agent to send ticket information from their support system to another application where a group of users can help them solve a customer's concern.

I'm in a dilemma whether the UI should just display the "ticket summary" field that the support agent should populate before sending to the other application or display a modal when the agent clicks on submit.

[The Mockup](https://app.moqups.com/idejesus@zendesk.com/X8amB8BI5I/view/page/a73f4772d) contains the two designs. The first mockup, Mockup A, will ask the user to fill in the "ticket summary" field before submitting it. The second mockup, Mockup B, will display a modal once the user clicks submit which will then require the agent to fill in the "ticket summary" field within the modal. If the agent closes the modal, what they typed will be saved and will reappear again when they try to submit the ticket again.

I'm biased to Mockup A because the user would be able to browse through the ticket conversation while typing in the "ticket summary" field.

**What are the advantages/disadvantages of both mockups?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the the limited information I have I can only provide limited advice. I am leaning towards mockup A because it requires less clicks and allows the user to remain on one screen rather than be focused into another modal window. I would recommend having an auotsave feature regardless so that if the agent has an interruption he can go back and continue his work. Without any more context of use I cannot provide any further feedback.  You should be aiming for ease of use and keeping key agent tasks clear of clutter. This means removing obstacles that get in the way of your user accomplishing their goals; in this case summarizing a support ticket and sending it to another user group. Do a usability test with a test scenario to find answers to your questions.